# Storing and "replaying" flask requests

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask system that will redirect users to a login page if they are not logged in.  However, after logging them in, I'd like to send them right back to whatever request they were making before I interrupted them with the login page.

For GET requests, this is relatively trivial, since all the important information is in the URL. But for a POST request, it's not so trivial, as there are a number of different properties one might want to access from the `request` proxy.

I would like to know whether I can somehow store/save a request (e.g., in a `before_request` function) before sending them to the login page, and essentially "replay" their original request again after they log in.

My current strategy has been to JSONify as much of the original `Request` object as I could, store it in a cookie, and then modify the `request` proxy in `before_request` to give it the properties of the previous request.

Although I can modify the `request` properties via something like `request.endpoint = "index"`, I can't seem to use `setattr(request, "endpoint", "index")` to set the values programmatically.

Does anybody know how to do that? Or, how one might get around this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a session object to save the original request; https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session

Comment: in `POST` you can also use `?redirect=url` like in `GET`

Comment: I'm essentially saving it in a session object right now. Not all of the Request object is able to be converted to JSON though. My biggest issue is turning the CURRENT `request` into the one I had saved

Comment: Not too versed on `events` listeners, but could it be something for your use-case? docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/event.html#)